# How do kill accolades work?

Tags: overwatch

You can get kill accolades in Overwatch, like Double Kills, Triple Kills, Quadruple Kills, Quintuple Kills, and Sextuple Kills.

What I want to know is, how long do I have between kills for them to count as a double kill, triple, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really not that much. I was playing on the Training camp and it wasn't more than 3 seconds for sure. I couldn't get past Quintuple Kill.

I don't have any links but I'd put my money on either 2 or 3 seconds.